# Get unique values of MS Excel AutoFilter in VBA

Tags: vba, excel

I have a function that filters (A) in a table:

```
(A) | B | C | D | E
 x
 x
 y
 x
 zx
```

Now I want to output all unique values in row (A)

-> 'x', 'y', 'zx'

before filtering, but have no clue how to get to this information.

```
Sub MakeFilter()
  Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A3:AT1000").AutoFilter field:=1, Criteria1:="x", _
       VisibleDropDown:=True
End Sub
```

In the image you can see how it is done manually. Peter is twice in the list, but in the filter selection list, it's only once. I want only those values in the selection box. All of them.

[First image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/run1m.png)
[Second image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nkqLb.png)

Comment: Can you please share your code?

Comment: I did, but it is very small code.

Comment: What do you mean with "I want to output ....options"???

Comment: Where do you want to output the options?

Comment: Are you just trying to do a "remove duplicates"?

Comment: Create a pivot table and drag column A to the rows. That will give you a distinct list of values

Comment: I want to write all variables (except duplicates) to a string vector. But basically a remove duplicate routine would be great too.
I want to print the output to a new sheet. The list I have has more than 1000 entries and I just want to check all possible values in the row.

Comment: Why do you want "2 times x"?  Wouldn't you just want it once?  Or do you need it output twice because you have "x", then "x" (counting as one output), then something else, then another "x" (counting as another output value)?

Comment: No I just want to do remove duplicates. I want to know which values exist. A histogram would be fine, but not necessary.

Comment: The bit in your question saying "-> 2 times x" is confusing, considering that the input has 3 "x"s and you are saying you want to remove duplicates.  But I have undeleted my answer which is similar to VBA Pete's (but written while he was writing his) except it uses a temporary worksheet and puts the values into an array at the end.

Comment: No, forget that, I've just caught up with the comments on VBA Pete's answer, and this is getting radically different to how it started - I think I will delete my answer as it will probably cause too much confusion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code below will copy column A into sheet 2, then remove all duplicates and apply your auto filter. You are better off using a loop to do the task described below:

```
Sub MakeFilter()

Dim ws As Worksheet
Dim wbnew As Workbook

x = 0

Set wbnew = Workbooks.Add(xlWBATWorksheet)

    For Each ws In ActiveWorkbook

    wbnew.Sheets(1).Range("A3:A1000").Offset(0, x).Value = ws.Sheets(1).Range("A3:A1000").Value

    wbnew.Sheets(1).Range("A3:A1000").Offset(0, x).RemoveDuplicates Columns:=Array(1), Header:=xlNo

    x = x + 1

    ws.Range("A3:AT1000").AutoFilter field:=1, Criteria1:="x", VisibleDropDown:=True

    Next ws

End Sub
```

Let me know if that helps.

Comment: Thanks, yes, somehow :). I have also 50 sheets in this workbook, so i think I will copy the table with removed duplicates to a new file.
It's just to analyse, which entries are in the sheet. I don't want to do it manually each time.

Comment: Do you want to create 50 new files from your sheets or one file with 50 columns?

Comment: I have one workbook with 50 sheets, each has a range (A3:AT1000) as a matrix. So I think I will copy the file manually and do in one file the filtering and in the other file the remove duplicates.
From the second file I want to know, which values exist, and maybe, how often do the exist. Then in the end I want to filter for one variable in the first file.

Comment: I think it does, thank you!! I thought it would be easier because (if you look in the 2nd image above), Excel already does this classification (Peter is twice in the list in image 1but only one time as a checkbox)

Comment: I got an error with your code: vba-compile-error-method-or-data-member-not-found